# Marquee animation doesn't run smooth

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animation

I create a top bar with a marquee effect. It is important that the marquee content (text) is immediately loaded because it's the first thing the user will see.

I have the following code:

```js
window.requestAnimationFrame = (function(){
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
          function( callback ){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
})();

var speed = 5000;
(function currencySlide(){
    var currencyPairWidth = $('.slideItem:first-child').outerWidth();
    $(".slideContainer").animate({marginLeft:-currencyPairWidth},speed, 'linear', function(){
        $(this).css({marginLeft:0}).find("li:last").after($(this).find("li:first"));
    });
    requestAnimationFrame(currencySlide);
})();
```

```css
.slider{
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
}

ul{
    background:#ddd;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:1000%;
    margin:0;
}
li{
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='slider'>
    <ul class="slideContainer">
        <li class="slideItem" >
            &nbsp;&nbsp;NEW&nbsp;&nbsp; + &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </li>
        <li class="slideItem" >
            &nbsp;&nbsp;NEW&nbsp;&nbsp; + &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </li>
        <li class="slideItem" >
            &nbsp;&nbsp;NEW&nbsp;&nbsp; + &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </li>
        <li class="slideItem" >
            &nbsp;&nbsp;NEW&nbsp;&nbsp; + &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </li>
        <li class="slideItem" >
            &nbsp;&nbsp;NEW&nbsp;&nbsp; + &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </li>
        <li class="slideItem" >
            &nbsp;&nbsp;NEW&nbsp;&nbsp; + &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </li>
        <li class="slideItem" >
            &nbsp;&nbsp;NEW&nbsp;&nbsp; + &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </li>
        <li class="slideItem" >
            &nbsp;&nbsp;NEW&nbsp;&nbsp; + &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </li>
        <li class="slideItem" >
            &nbsp;&nbsp;NEW&nbsp;&nbsp; + &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </li>
        <li class="slideItem" >
            &nbsp;&nbsp;NEW&nbsp;&nbsp; + &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </li>
        <li class="slideItem" >
            &nbsp;&nbsp;NEW&nbsp;&nbsp; + &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </li>
        <li class="slideItem" >
            &nbsp;&nbsp;NEW&nbsp;&nbsp; + &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </li>
        <li class="slideItem" >
            &nbsp;&nbsp;NEW&nbsp;&nbsp; + &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </li>
        <li class="slideItem" >
            &nbsp;&nbsp;NEW&nbsp;&nbsp; + &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </li>
        <li class="slideItem" >
            &nbsp;&nbsp;NEW&nbsp;&nbsp; + &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </li>
        <li class="slideItem" >
            &nbsp;&nbsp;NEW&nbsp;&nbsp; + &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </li>
        <li class="slideItem" >
            &nbsp;&nbsp;NEW&nbsp;&nbsp; + &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </li>
        <li class="slideItem" >
            &nbsp;&nbsp;NEW&nbsp;&nbsp; + &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </li>
        <li class="slideItem" >
            &nbsp;&nbsp;NEW&nbsp;&nbsp; + &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </li>
        <li class="slideItem" >
            &nbsp;&nbsp;NEW&nbsp;&nbsp; + &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </li>
        <li class="slideItem" >
            &nbsp;&nbsp;NEW&nbsp;&nbsp; + &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </li>
        <li class="slideItem" >
            &nbsp;&nbsp;NEW&nbsp;&nbsp; + &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </li>
        <li class="slideItem" >
            &nbsp;&nbsp;NEW&nbsp;&nbsp; + &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The problem: Every 5 seconds the animation is not smooth anymore. It shakes a little bit.
Tested in Google Chrome browser on MacOS.

What changes can I make to my code so that the animation is always smooth?

I appreciate your time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem is with `display: inline-block` causing an "invisible margin". More information here: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

I used the solution mentioned in the article and added the following CSS:

```css
ul {
    font-size: 0;
}

ul li {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Now it's working as expected!